# Flex 4.5 Mobile - Facebook Authorisation

Tags: ios, facebook, actionscript, facebook-graph-api, flex4.5

I am creating an iOS app using Flex 4.5 (Flash Builder 5.5) and I want to authorise my user with the Facebook API. Google isn't turning up any answers as to how to do this, and the Facebook documentation obviously only shows you how to do it using Cocoa. Whilst I can obviously make the HTTP request, the Facebook API expects a return uri argument, and I don't want my user to be able to authenticate the app seamlessly like Tweetdeck or other apps that use Facebook.

Has anyone managed to authorise a mobile app build in Flex with Facebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the Facebook Action Script API:
http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/

The current API contains `com.facebook.graph.FacebookMobile` so you may want to look at that if you haven't already.

While I haven't developed a mobile app in Flex that authorises in Facebook, I have developed a desktop application in Flex that does using `com.facebook.graph.FacebookDesktop`.

Alternatively you can try to [authenticate directly](http://www.subotnik.com/blog/2011/01/mobile-facebook-oauth-authentication-with-air-2-5/).